# How to intercept unpinned from the top via Python Telegram Bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

in my Telegram Bot, built with Python Telegram Bot, I need to add an handler that intercepts unpinned messages. Among the filters (https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.2/telegram.ext.filters.html) I find only "PINNED_MESSAGE" that correctly intercepts pinned messages but there is no opposite. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

I expected there to be an UNPINNED MESSAGE filter but there is none.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does not provide service messages for that.

On a side note please notice that the `python-telegram-bot` team does not support v13.x anymore and that you are encouraged to upgrade to v20.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.